# Why are both tabs running in FragmentTabs?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using FragmentTabsPager, and when my app starts, both tabs initiate net-requests to fetch their content....I would expect the first tab to load onAppStart, and the second tab to load when it is clicked, this is not the case as they are both loading simultaneously onAppStart why is this the case?

Comment: Can you post the code associated with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each tab within a FragmentTabsPager runs a Fragment, which is essentially an activity within a single view. It has its own lifecycle and behaves similarly to an actual Activity.

Comment: this is just a restatement of basic tab behavior and no effort has been made to answer the question.

Comment: Actually, it did answer the question.  The reason both are loading simultaneously is because onCreate() is being called when the activity starts, just as in the default activity lifecycle.

Comment: well he's correct and that is the answer. The Fragments have parallel lifecycles and they co-exist accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your Fragment from the onTabClick (or equivalent event) in the parent